# calc() not working for 100% high bootstrap accordion in a fixed div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, calc

I am making a feed page in bootstrap. Left section is the feed list and right section is the feed details area. I have made feed details section fixed so when scrolling down the list, the feed details always shows to the right.

The Feed details section is made of:

---

### 1. Feed Details: calc(100% - 80px)

### 2. Comments: calc(100% - 80px)

### 3. post comment (height: 80px)

The problem is '1' and '2' above are two tabs of an accordion. and i want at least one of them to be open at any given time. thats done.

also if the content is small like no comments, i want the comments section to take up all the available space. but if the content is too much i have set the content overflow to slider.

in my particular case if the window is maximized in firefox, if i give the panel body of '1' to min-height:390px; and max-height:390px; all goes well but of course with different window size the accordion starts merging with the form below.

here is the code:

```
<!-- right section : Feed Details -->
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div id="feed-detail">
                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                      <i class="icon ion-android-list"></i>
                                      Feed Details
                                    </a>
                                  </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                    <h4>Waqar Younis steps down as Pakistan coach</h4>
                                    <p>Description of the feed if any. consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque aut amet, alias consectetur voluptatibus aliquid dicta deleniti cupiditate! Officiis nulla, rem nobis sequi cupiditate incidunt magni itaque repudiandae quidem autem quisquam corporis, quod, enim perspiciatis.</p>
                                    <ul class="list-inline">
                                        <li><i class="icon ion-eye"></i> Seen by: <strong><a href="#">6</a></strong></li>
                                        <li><i class="icon ion-android-share"></i> Shared with: <strong><a href="#">All Groups</a></strong></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="list-inline feed-gallery">
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/waqar-1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/waqar-2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/waqar-3.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                      <i class="icon ion-android-textsms"></i>
                                      View all 34 comments
                                    </a>
                                  </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                                  <div class="panel-body" id="feed-comments">
                                    <div class="media">
                                      <div class="media-left pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">
                                          <img class="media-object" src="images/avatar-mini-2.jpg" alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Julia Roberts
                                            <span class="pull-right">2 min ago</span>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti numquam vel totam! Autem porro culpa alias dolorem tempore deserunt sed earum, minus labore nemo ea!</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media">
                                      <div class="media-left pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">
                                          <img class="media-object" src="images/avatar-mini.jpg" alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Frank Allen
                                            <span class="pull-right">2 min ago</span>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti numquam vel totam! Autem porro culpa alias dolorem tempore deserunt sed earum, minus labore nemo ea!</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media">
                                      <div class="media-left pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">
                                          <img class="media-object" src="images/avatar-mini-4.jpg" alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Mark Henry
                                            <span class="pull-right">2 min ago</span>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti numquam vel totam! Autem porro culpa alias dolorem tempore deserunt sed earum, minus labore nemo ea!</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media">
                                      <div class="media-left pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">
                                          <img class="media-object" src="images/avatar-mini-3.jpg" alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Cathy Pacific
                                            <span class="pull-right">2 min ago</span>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti numquam vel totam! Autem porro culpa alias dolorem tempore deserunt sed earum, minus labore nemo ea!</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media">
                                      <div class="media-left pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">
                                          <img class="media-object" src="images/avatar-mini-4.jpg" alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Samatha Auguelera
                                            <span class="pull-right">2 min ago</span>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti numquam vel totam! Autem porro culpa alias dolorem tempore deserunt sed earum, minus labore nemo ea!</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media">
                                      <div class="media-left pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">
                                          <img class="media-object" src="images/avatar-mini.jpg" alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>George Cloony
                                            <span class="pull-right">2 min ago</span>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti numquam vel totam! Autem porro culpa alias dolorem tempore deserunt sed earum, minus labore nemo ea!</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media">
                                      <div class="media-left pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">
                                          <img class="media-object" src="images/avatar-mini-2.jpg" alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Brad Pittsburg
                                            <span class="pull-right">2 min ago</span>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti numquam vel totam! Autem porro culpa alias dolorem tempore deserunt sed earum, minus labore nemo ea!</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media">
                                      <div class="media-left pull-left">
                                        <a href="#">
                                          <img class="media-object" src="images/avatar-mini.jpg" alt="...">
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4>Hammad
                                            <span class="pull-right">2 min ago</span>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti numquam vel totam! Autem porro culpa alias dolorem tempore deserunt sed earum, minus labore nemo ea!</p>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 comment-control" style="">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post your comment">
                                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Post!</button>
                                  </span>
                                </div><!-- /input-group -->
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
        <style>
#feed-detail{
width: 420px; height: calc(100% - 100px);position: fixed;background: #333;
}
#feed-detail .panel-body h4{font-weight: 700;font-size: 18px; color: #666; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; margin-top: 0;}
.form-control:focus, #focusedInput {border: none;}
.comment-control {position:absolute; bottom:0; padding:3px;}
.comment-control input[type=text]{ height:auto; line-height: 30px;}
.comment-control button{ padding: 11px; background: #f8f8f8; border-radius: 0;border: none;}
.comment-control button:hover{background: #f6f6f6; color:#333; border: none;}

.comment-control input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder, .comment-control input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder, .comment-control input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder, .comment-control input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder
{ color: #ccc; }
#feed-detail .panel{background: #eee; border-radius: 0 !important;}
#feed-detail .panel .panel-heading{background: none; border-radius: 0 !important;}
#feed-detail .panel .panel-heading:hover{background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05); 

border-radius: 0 !important;}
/*--------- Here i need the calc(100%-80px) in working order ---------*/
#feed-detail .panel-body{
min-height: 390px;
max-height: 390px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#feed-detail .panel-body li{margin-right: 20px;}
#feed-comments .media-body h4{font-size: 14px; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;}
#feed-comments .media-body h4 span{font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400;}
#feed-detail ul.feed-gallery li img{height: 80px; width: auto; border-radius: 0; background-color: #eee;}
#feed-detail ul.feed-gallery li img:hover{background-color: #fff;}
#feed-detail ul.feed-gallery li {margin: 0 2px 2px 0; padding:0;}
#feed-detail i {font-size: 1em; margin-right: 5px;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 6px;}

.people-options .bootstrap-select{margin-bottom: 0 !important;}
            </style>
```

I have tried every combination, feels like i have hit a brick wall. Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Imran

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
element{
height:calc(100vh - 80px)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will try it and will come back to you.